# Photoshop-esque blend mode in web pages using CSS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-processing, blending

I am wondering if it is possible to blend two or more images together on a webpage using blend modes like you will find in photoshop (overlay, screen, lighten, etc).

I know that this kind of thing is possible with flash and java, but is it possible without any plugins i.e. with CSS or JavaScript? I have seen a few javascript examples of this effect that work on relatively small images, but I am interested in performing this on high resolution images... this is purely for experimental purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the canvas element, you can get overlay and lighten pretty easily.  It's all about what settings you specify before rendering each bitmap to the canvas.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing

Answer (score 5):

I have created a separate, lightweight, open-source library for perform Photoshop-style blend modes from one HTML Canvas context to another: [context-blender](https://github.com/Phrogz/context-blender). Here's the sample usage:

```
// Might be an 'offscreen' canvas
var over  = someCanvas.getContext('2d');
var under = anotherCanvas.getContext('2d');

over.blendOnto( under, 'screen', {destX:30,destY:15} );
```

See the [README](https://github.com/Phrogz/context-blender#readme) for more information, including the blend modes supported in the current version.

Comment: What's the efficiency like on this library?

Comment: @Greg I get ~210fps on a straight copy of a 141x141 region, and ~160fps performing "difference" mode (the current worse performer), using Safari v5. Performance on Chrome is better, Firefox is worse. There's only one main optimization that I have (intentionally) not made: right now there is a `switch` inside a `for` looping over the pixels. Exploding the loops inside each `case` instead provides about a 5-10% speed boost, but at an ugly, non-DRY expansion of the code base, duplicating calculations common to all modes.

Comment: @Greg The library is currently a readable [145 lines of code](https://github.com/Phrogz/context-blender/blob/master/context_blender.js) (with about 14 of those being comments that I really need to just delete).

Comment: @Phrogz - First off, thanks for the code base. I'm working with it right now. I noticed the switch statement being inside the loop. Is there any reason it's in there like that other than for ease of coding?

Comment: @Di-0xide See my comment above from Dec 20; it's as it is for convenience and DRYness. If you need absolute speed you can move the loops inside the switch and possibly receive a moderate performance gain.

Comment: @Phrogz - That's what I figured. I'll play with it later on and see if there's any significant performance increase.

Comment: @Phrogz: Thanks for this! I found your example a bit hard to follow for simply wanting to blend two canvases on a page, but I muddled through and eventually got it figured out. Would you be interested in suggestions for improving the documentation?

Comment: @ScottCranfill Absolutely, thank you. You can email me directly at the address found on http://phrogz.net/contact (or https://github.com/phrogz/ if that address does not work).